# Broad Strokes - missing letter riddle

Tags: word

There are two five-letter words that belong together (a common object)

```
_ _ _ _ _       _ _ _ _ _
```

In each step, it is possible to remove a letter from each word, and create two new words that still make sense (though they may not relate to each other that much).  In each instance, the position of the letter removed is the same, though the letters may be different.  The order of other letters may not be rearranged.

As an example,  consider the following two words...

```
VENT   SOAP
```

In this case, the third letter of each word can be removed to become

```
VET    SOP
```

To give a little hint, please consider the following clues for the words I am thinking of

```
_ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _  ??? - the final answer
_ _ _ _     _ _ _ _    A small shrub
_ _ _       _ _ _      Passenger vehicle with sharp edges
_ _         _ _        Sample answer to the question of "where is love?"
```

**Also**, bonus points to whoever comes up with a list longer than the one I have (I haven't put much thought into it, so interested to see what others can come up with).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe..

> ```
>  paint brush    - the final answer (common object, "broad strokes")
>  pint  bush     A small shrub
>  pin   bus      Passenger vehicle with sharp edges
>  in    us       Sample answer to the question of "where is love?"
> ```

I highlighted the removed letters to show that in each case they were removed from the same position, as required.

Comment: Was it too easy?

Comment: @APrough pretty easy, but definitely not "too". Like [Elpharya](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/79971/36023), I had a bit of trouble going from shortest to longer (the first three letter word doesn't match the clue all that perfectly), but since the second word worked out nicely all the way up to five letters, it was just a matter of figuring out the common object, and working my way back down. All in all, a nice and very enjoyable puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

A (very) partial answer:
    _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _  ??? - the final answer

> "t_iny" "brush"

_ _ _ _  -   _ _ _ _    A small shrub

> "tiny" "bush"

_ _ _    -   _ _ _      Passenger vehicle with sharp edges

> "tin" "bus"

_ _     -    _ _        Sample answer to the question of "where is love?"

> "in" "us"